# Haskell WinGHC Running Program with Performance Statistics

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction

Using WinGHC how can i run my program with the +RTS -sstderr option to get statistics like compile time, memory useage or anything else of interest?

Currently i am using the command line: ghc -rtsopts -O3 -prof -auto-all Main.hs

Comment: Help us to help you. What have you tried? Show us your command line. How are you building your program? If you're using cabal, show us your .cabal file. If not, show us the ghc command you use to compile your program.

Comment: i have added my current command line, is this what requires changing ?

Comment: Not sure what "WinGHC" is. If it is just the Windows binary of GHC, `-rtsopts` should give you access to the `-s` stats. If you want the time and memory consumption of the compilation, you need to pass `+RTS -s` or similar to the GHC invocation, `ghc +RTS -s -RTS -O2 -prof -fprof-auto Main.hs`.

Comment: It gives me an error of '<interactive>:10:1: Not in scope: `ghc''. Perhaps i am executing this wrong.

Comment: does it go in my code or command line ?

Comment: Command line. Can you clarify what you want exactly, and what problems you encounter trying to achieve that? I'm a bit confused what the situation is.

Comment: Basically i am trying to get performance statistics on my haskell program. I cannot figure out how to compile my program using flags...How do i add a flag when compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using WinGHCi set your active directory where your program is e.g.

```
 Prelude> :cd C:\Haskell
```

Then, when you are in the right directory as per previous comments above enter:

```
Prelude> :! ghc +RTS -s -RTS -O2 -prof -fprof-auto Main.hs
```

The 'Main.hs' should be your program name.

This will then give statistics as follows:

```
 152,495,848 bytes allocated in the heap
  36,973,728 bytes copied during GC
  10,458,664 bytes maximum residency (5 sample(s))
   1,213,516 bytes maximum slop
          21 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
 Gen  0       241 colls,     0 par    0.14s    0.20s     0.0008s    0.0202s
 Gen  1         5 colls,     0 par    0.08s    0.12s     0.0233s    0.0435s
 etc..........
 etc.............
```

Other flags can be set to see other statistics.

Comment: Thats exactly, what i was looking for. I was missing the ':!' bit. Thanks.